# How can I use the value from "Run Parameter" in "Copy artifacts from another project" for our Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job I want to use to run automation on a build created in another job. I want the user to specify that build job's build number using the drop-down box created by the Run Parameter plug-in and then have the automation job copy the artifacts from the user-specified build job.

These are the settings for Run Parameter:

- Name: BUILD_SELECTOR
- Project: Foo
- Filter: All Builds

The user then selects a build like  which is saved to BUILD_SELECTOR like "https://blah.com/job/Foo/4/"

Then later in my job, I have Copy artifacts from another project and I want to copy the artifact from the job selected above:

- Project Name: Foo
- Which build: ?

This is where I get stumped. I have tried the URL above as a permanent link and also tried stripping out the "4" above for Specific build, but nothing seems to work. How can I use that value to do what I need to do?

Comment: parametrized builds values are exposed as ENV variables, so you should be able to access it as $BUILD_SELECTOR; with the copy artifacts plugin, it should be enough to select "build parameter" in the "which build" field

Comment: It gives me ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: Foo. Any other ideas, @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21519

You can use ${BUILD_SELECTOR_NUMBER} to get just the build number which you can use with specific build.